# UISearchBar Facebook app style iOS 7

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar, ios7

I'm trying to make a generic UISearchBar for my app, the goal is to press the tipical magnifier button in the UINavigationBar and show the search (as an example the new facebook app).

I'm able to add the UISearchBar in an UITableView and make the filter, but what i need is to pop the UISearchView and search in other place (BBDD, txt, etc), where to search is not the problem, the problem is to show or pop the UISearchBar in a generic way and not atached to the UINavigationBar.

Can you point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in Facebook app, when you tap on magnifier icon, it adds a new view controller .i.e table view controller and shows it modaly. Background color is clear when there is no record. and solid when there are  records.
So. You present a Modal view controller with UISearchBar and TableView. Keep there background clear. And when there you will add your cells in table view it will fill the background color, and If you want to set whole view controller background to solid white, change it to solid white when you found some results.
Any thing needs to be more clear ask me.

Comment: thanks for the aproach i will try it, i think that is the right direcction